# "Sharing CANDY" on SPOJ

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

How can I improve it and its running time efficiency?

**Problem ([SPOJ/CANDY](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY/))**

> Jennifer is a teacher in the first year of a primary school. She has
>   gone for a trip with her class today. She has taken a packet of
>   candies for each child. Unfortunately, the sizes of the packets are
>   not the same.
>
> Jennifer is afraid that each child will want to have the biggest
>   packet of candies and this will lead to quarrels or even fights among
>   children. She wants to avoid this. Therefore, she has decided to open
>   all the packets, count the candies in each packet and move some
>   candies from bigger packets to smaller ones so that each packet will
>   contain the same number of candies. The question is how many candies
>   she has to move.
>
> **Input specification**
>
> The input file consists of several blocks of data. Each block starts
>   with the number of candy packets \$N (1 <= N <= 10000)\$ followed by
>   \$N\$ integers (each less than 1000) in separate lines, giving the
>   number of candies in each packet. After the last block of data there
>   is the number -1.
>
> **Output specification**
>
> The output file should contain one line with the smallest number of
>   moves for each block of data. One move consists of taking one candy
>   from a packet and putting it into another one. If it is not possible
>   to have the same number of candies in each packet, output the number
>   -1.

**Solution**

```
 //candy.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string n;
int avg,t,k; // t = test cases , avg = average
while(true)
{
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int sum = 0; // initialise sum and cnt(next line) to 0 
    int cnt = 0;
    if(t == -1) // Last line to end the program(Mentioned in the ques.)
        break;

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)
        {
            cin >> n[i];
            sum += n[i];
        }

        if(sum % t != 0) // If it is not possible to have the same number of candies in each packet, output the number -1(mentioned in the question)
            cout << "-1" << endl;   

        else
        {
            avg = sum/t;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)
            {
                k = n[i];               
                while(k > avg) //Adds the moves 
                {
                    k-- ;
                    cnt++ ;
                }
            }   
            printf("%d\n", cnt);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really silly:

> ```
> while(k > avg) //Adds the moves 
> {
>     k-- ;
>     cnt++ ;
> }
> ```

When you can do the same thing in one step:

```
if (k > avg) cnt += k - avg;
```

I don't see anything else to make this faster. But there are many many coding style issues.

#### Limit the scope of variables

Instead of declaring all the variables at the top,
it's better to declare them in the smallest scope, for example:

```
int avg = sum/t;
for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)
{
    int k = n[i];               
    if (k > avg) cnt += k - avg;
}
```

#### Use the right types

Why do you read the numbers into a `string`?
The program won't work if a pocket contains more than 9 candies,
which it might, since the requirement states *"less than 1000"*.
Use an `int[]` instead.

#### Misc

- You should not `using namespace std`
- You're mixing C++ style input/output using `cin/cout` and old-style `scanf/printf`. Since you're in C++, you should use C++ everywhere consistently
- It's recommended to use braces even with single-statement `if`s and loops
- After the `break` statement, you can simplify a bit by eliminating the `else` block

#### Corrected and improved implementation

With the above suggestions, the implementation becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int t;
        std::cin >> t;
        if (t == -1) {
            break;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        int n[t];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> n[i];
            sum += n[i];
        }

        if (sum % t != 0) {
            std::cout << "-1" << std::endl;   
            continue;
        }

        int avg = sum/t;
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++)
        {
            int k = n[i];               
            if (k > avg) cnt += k - avg;
        }   
        std::cout << cnt << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Take special note as to how each variable is declared and initialized right before it's really needed.

Comment: In competitive programming time really matters and trust me scanf , print is faster than cin , cout so yeah I use scanf and printf in some cases.

Comment: In the many contests I've participated, I've never seen that `scanf` vs `cin` would make a decisive difference. In time limit exceeded situations it's always the algorithm that was inefficient. That doesn't mean there cannot be exceptions, if you say it's a necessary micro-optimization for this contest, then I'll "trust you". But my recommendation as good C++ programming style still stands. Feel free to modify it for your contest submission.